# If I don't kill Syreena will she show up later?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So in the smuggler storyline, right before you leave Ord Mantell, you have the option to kill or not kill Syreena. If you choose not to, will she show up later in the storyline?

Comment: Should this be marked up and title adjusted due to spoilers?

Comment: I would doubt it -- choices tend to only have immediate effects from what I've seen.

Comment: Sadly not, but she will at least send you an email. I was really hoping she'd turn out to be a companion. You know, instead of the highly annoying Corso and his harpoon shot that he insists on turning back on every 5 minutes. Oh Corso, how I hate you.

Comment: for Scoundrels, that harpoon shot is awesome, but I can see how it'd be a pain for gunslingers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having played the smuggler line up to 30+ I have not seen her reappear yet. There will be many other interesting characters that come into the story line though.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as correct, but if she does show back up please come back and post as much.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the missions where Syreena appears:

http://www.wikiswtor.com/Syreena

It seems that the mission which allows you to kill her is the last one anyway.